# How to give a variable inside sql in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am inserting data to a data list in asp.net. I need to modify the Select Command according to my needs. I did something like this,

```
string query = "SELECT [movieName], [sDate], [eDate], [IMDb], [imageUrl] FROM [movieDrama] WHERE ([category]='Drama' AND [movieName] like '%@key%') ORDER BY [movieName]";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;
```

But this is not working. I think I did something wrong when defining '@key'. How to do it in correct way? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

Use it like;

```
LIKE '%' + @key + '%'
```

instead of

```
LIKE '%@key%'
```

For full query;

```
string query = "SELECT [movieName], [sDate], [eDate], [IMDb], [imageUrl] FROM [movieDrama] WHERE ([category]='Drama' AND [movieName] LIKE '%' + @key + '%') ORDER BY [movieName]";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
```

And actually, you don't need square brackets every column of your query, you just need to use when you want use some *[reserved keywords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* as a column names.

Comment: This is not really dynamic, what if he wants to change it to `%key` not `%key%`? Of course he has to modify the query.

Comment: @LIH Did you debug your code? What is look like your `query` when you pas `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);` line ?

Comment: Have you tried running the resulting query manually with the appropriate value ?

Comment: It gives this "Must declare the scalar variable "@key" '

Comment: @LIH So that means there is no variable called `key` in your code. Where this `key` coming from ?

Comment: There is a variable called key.
        string key = Request.QueryString["searchKey"];

Comment: @LIH What is look like your `query` when you pas `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);` line ?

Comment: I am writing this code using visual studio inside a .cs file. Sorry I didn't understand what you just asked. I am new to asp since this is my first project.

Answer (score 2):

Just this:

```
string query = "SELECT [movieName], [sDate], [eDate], [IMDb], [imageUrl] FROM [movieDrama] WHERE ([category]='Drama' AND [movieName] like @key) ORDER BY [movieName]";
```

then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", "%"+ key + "%");
```

Comment: @LIH what if you remove all the `AND [movieName] like @key` from the query?

Comment: @LIH returning `empty result` doesn't mean it doesn't work. You should try `executing` the same query in your `query editor` to see if it returns any result. Or you should post some sample `key` and your `records`.

Comment: No it returns this error "Must declare the scalar variable "@key""

Comment: @LIH what is this `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;`? I think you mean `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = cmd;`?

Comment: I tried it.  then it gives this error. "Could not find server 'System' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers."

Comment: @LIH if so, the problem is in your `connection`, you should update your question (at the bottom) with the connection string info, others may help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your sqlCommand the connection parameter:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,YOURCONNECTIONSTRING);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", key)
```